# Pause and resume threads in ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, threadpool

In my example I have:

**Task** - does some long running operations in background thread: looping over large data set and do some other heavy operations for each item.

**TaskExecutor** - put `Task` to execute in background `Thread` from `ThreadPool`.

**Caller** - client requests `TaskExecutor` to start, pause and resume `Task` at some point.

```
class TaskExecutor {
    val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) as ThreadPoolExecutor

    // begin API methods section
    fun submitTask() {
        threadPool.submit(Task())
    }

    fun pauseThreadPool() {
        // pause all threads (in this example just one thread) in threadPool
    }

    fun resumeThreadPool() {
        // resume all threads (in this example just one thread) in threadPool
    }
    // end API methods section

    fun runTask() {
        for(item in items) {
            // do something with item
        }

    }

    inner class Task(): Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            runTask()
        }           
    }
}
```

```
class Caller() {
    val taskExecutor = TaskExecutor()
    taskExecutor.submitTask()
    ...
    ...
    taskExecutor.pauseThreadPool()
    ...
    ...
    taskExecutor.resumeThreadPool()
}
```

**Question**: is there any possibility to pause `ThreadPool`(or `Thread` from `ThreadPool`) and resume it by Caller to call `pauseThreadPool()` and `resumeThreadPool()` functions when it needs. Expected time for ThreadPool to be on pause is up to a few minutes.

Comment: fantaghirocco, did you try that? I tried accepted solution from the question you shared and it doesn't work for me, thread is not pausing with that solution. That is why i asked this question.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt it is possible to anyhow pause threads. You need to implement this at the tasks level. If I understand mentioned example properly, it pauses starting of new tasks, but it doesn't pause already running tasks.

Comment: broot, ohh..I see your point. I think you are right, yes, I've just tested, it pauses starting of new tasks(runnable/thread) in threadpool, but not the current which is running now and has been submitted before the pause. In my scenario I need to pause already submitted and running task. Correct, I can do pause at the task level(in for loop, etc.), but I was thinking if pause can be done for the whole Thread, like sleep(), but in more better approach.